# DEPRECATION:', 'Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated, please use the specFilter option in configure'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm using karma + jasmine in my angular 6 application and I'm receiving the following warining:

> DEPRECATION:', 'Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated,
>   please use the specFilter option in configure'

What should I do to make solve this warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was using the version 1.1.1 of `karma-jasmine` package.

Reading [this](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-chrome-launcher/issues/190) post, I updated it to version 2.0.1 and the warning disappeared.

Comment: I read the same post and have the same version but still see error.