# Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner

These are my setup after I upgraded to Agnular 7 and TypeScript 3.2. I'm running karma jasmine tests using these packages.

> "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
>
> "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
>
> "karma": "^4.0.1",
>
> "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
>
> "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
>
> "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
>
> "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
>
> "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
>
> "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
>
> "karma-trx-reporter": "^0.4.0",

The tests pass by I still see these depredations.

> 'DEPRECATION:', 'Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated,
>   please use the specFilter option in `configure`'
>
> 'DEPRECATION:', 'Getting specFilter directly from Env is deprecated,
>   please check the specFilter option from `configuration`'
>
> 'DEPRECATION:', 'Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated,
>   please use the specFilter option in `configure`'

I have looked at this question and tried the fix and the quoted link, but didn't work for me:
[DEPRECATION:', 'Setting specFilter directly on Env is deprecated, please use the specFilter option in configure'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53724061/1019042)